# is there any "no licence - free" dynamic toolkit controls for visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to learn, is there any toolkit that I use in visual studio web project(MVC). I know some toolkit; such as Telerik, Kendo, Trirand. But all of them need licence. I make web project and need to use dynamic grid etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple googling would answer your question, try searching by `grid js` or `toolkit js` or `javascript toolkit`

also you find in this wikipedia article some comparison between diffrent JavaScript frameworks.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks

Comment: I found jquery grid but I don't know how it can programming...

Comment: Try googling with "jquery ui asp.net mvc tutorial" and you will find tons of great articles that explains  how it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [MVC Controls Toolkit](http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/). Although I'm not sure if it works with ASP.NET MVC 5, the web site only mentions versions 2 to 4.